# Update list of dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have following 2 lists of dict:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'value': '1'}, {'id': 2, 'value': '2'}, {'id': 3, 'value': '3'}]
b = [{'id': 2, 'value': '2.0'}]
```

I am expecting 3rd list(or update **list a**) such that the output will reflect **list b in list a** (compairision will be based on *id*). So, in above case, result will be:

```
c = [{'id': 1, 'value': '1'}, {'id': 2, 'value': '2.0'}, {'id': 3, 'value': '3'}]
```

Any clue on how to do this rather than the traditional way of looping through both the list?

Comment: Why not just use a dict of <id : value> mappings?

Comment: I used dict with just 2 keys for the example over here. In reality, dict is huge with over 10 keys and id is defined by 4 keys. I can still understand that it's possible to implement in the same way as you said. But that will turn task into huge one due to multiple functionalities dependent on the format mentioned above.

Comment: What volume of data are you working with? The currently accepted answer will take way too long on large data.

Comment: Usually, it's around 100-200 records in list a (can go upto 500) and around 5-50 records in list b.

Comment: Yeah... if you can't make them dicts to begin with, you want to squeeze out as much performance as you can.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no choice but to work with clunky structures like this, you can at least try and make this as efficient as possible.

The other answers give you quadratic time solutions. But you can cut this down to linear - a big improvement - with a little preprocessing.

```
b = {d['id'] : d for d in b}
a_new = [b.get(d['id'], d) for d in a]
```

```
print(a_new)
[{'id': 1, 'value': '1'}, {'id': 2, 'value': '2.0'}, {'id': 3, 'value': '3'}]
```

The idea is to put `b` into a dict of  mappings. Lookups become constant time, saving you an entire loop traversal.

Comment: Way better than _[j if i["id"] == j["id"] else i for i in a for j in b]_

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
[j if i["id"] == j["id"] else i for i in a for j in b]
```

Output

> [{'id': 1, 'value': '1'}, {'id': 2, 'value': '2.0'}, {'id': 3,
>   'value': '3'}]

Comment: Thanks mate. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @743 This is inefficient. It needs two loops. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:-**

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'value': '1'}, {'id': 2, 'value': '2'}, {'id': 3, 'value': '3'}]
b = [{'id': 2, 'value': '2.0'}]
for i in a:
    for j in b:    
        if i['id'] == j['id']:
            i['value'] = j['value']
print (a) #expected output
```

Comment: Even though it will work, I was trying to avoid this